# Read excel file in c# using dynamic keyword

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, excel-2007

How can I read the excel file using C# 4.0. Once I saw in some video it becomes very easy to read the file using dynamic keyword but now when I search to find any tutorial, I can't seem to find any. Can anybody point me in some direction or give some snippet that reads from excel file (.xlxs). I only want to read the first sheet but that sheet can contains any columns and rows. I want to read them all. The data contained in the sheet is just simply numbers and strings. No more than that!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: are you looking for these? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=weNiluyoGSs and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QP8vcz8HgNI

Comment: @Bob Lee Swagger - yes worked in elan but this not place where we talk contact me on "pranayamr at gmail.com"

Comment: @Bob Lee Swagger -  dont forget to accept answer if you got the info you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't directly answer, but I would like to recommend you use the [Excel Data Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/), which is opensource under the LGPL licence. Using the dynamic keyword means using the COM interop of the Excel, which may be slower than the former and would annoy you with using the dynamic keyword.

Comment: Ado.Net code didn't work. But this one works. So I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to read it better to go for `OleDb`  rather than going for dynamic

Something like this

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

... 

String sConnectionString = 
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
"Data Source=" + [Your Excel File Name Here] + ";" +
"Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";


OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);

objConn.Open();

OleDbCommand objCmdSelect =new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", objConn);

OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();

objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;

DataSet objDataset1 = new DataSet();

objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1);

objConn.Close();
```

Comment: I already tried this code before only. The code stuck at this line `objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1);` It doesn't work. Does this require Excel to be installed? or will it do if it is not installed?

Comment: I dont think that require excel

Comment: Infact now it gets stuck on `objConn.Open();`. Btw, you worked in elan. I worked there too. I recently left ;)

Comment: Most probably the reason why the connection can't be opened is that you're running your application in 64bit mode. The Jet driver is 32bit only - so change your platform from "Any CPU" to "X86" and see if it works then. No, Excel does not have to be installed in order to read the file using a database connection.

Comment: The problem is the program doesn't throw any exceptions. It just hangs forever using Ado.Net. I am using WPF4. Changing to x64 or x86 doesn't help either. From where the error is coming is not known. Basically the program just hangs.